# ProgressMonitor always finishes at 100 even after increasing maximum

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker, progressmonitor

I have a `ProgressMonitor` that shows while I process some database tables.  The number of tables is not known at first, so I create the `ProgressMonitor` with a maximum value of 100.

Once processing has begun in the `SwingWorker` thread, it gets the number of tables and sets the maximum of the `ProgressMonitor` to the number of tables (about 530 in my test). However, the `ProgressMonitor` still finishes at 100 and stops the execution of the thread, even though the maximum has increased and the progress bar shows 100/530 accurately.

Any idea why this happens?

The `actionListener` to start the `ProgressMonitor` and `SwingWorker` (named TaskThread) from the button press:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    if (cmd.equals("generate")) {
        progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(this, "Generating...", "", 0, 100);
        task = new TaskThread();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        task.execute();
        genButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

`PropertyChangeListener` that updates the `ProgressMonitor`:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) 
{
    if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName() ) 
    {
        int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
        progressMonitor.setProgress(progress);
        String message = String.format("Completed %d%%.\n", progress);
        progressMonitor.setNote(message);
        if (progressMonitor.isCanceled() || task.isDone()) 
        {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            if (progressMonitor.isCanceled()) {
                task.cancel(true);
            }
            genButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The `SwingWorker` class:

```
class TaskThread extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> 
{
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() 
    {
        String tableList = tablesArea.getText().trim();
        script = "";
        String filename = outPath.getText

        // Connect to Database
        Connection conn = getDbConnection();
        if (conn == null)
            return null;

        try {
            // if tableList is blank, get all tables from the From Database afm_tbls table
            if (tableList.equals(""))
            {
                // code omitted
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            canWriteFile = false;
            handleError(se);
        }

        String[] tables = tableList.split(",");
        generateRecordCount(conn, tables);

        // Close the connection
        if(conn != null)
        {
            try {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }

        // Write SQL code to a file
        writeScript(filename);

        return null;
    }

    private void generateRecordCount(Connection conn, String[] tables)
    {
        setProgressMax(tables.length);
        setProgress(0);

        // Loop through tables  
        for (int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
        {
            // Get record count for each table
            try { 
                String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS reccount FROM " + tables[i];
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                rs.next();

                int recCount = rs.getInt("reccount");
                if (recCount > 0)
                    script += tables[i] + ": " + recCount + nl;

                // Set progress of SwingWorker, ProgressMonitor is updated by PropertyChangeListener
                int prog = getProgress() + 1;
                setProgress(prog);
            }
            catch(SQLException se)
            {
                handleError(se);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why.  So hopefully for someone else's benefit, here is the problem:

The [SwingWorker.setProgress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress%28int%29) function has bounds of 0 and 100, so even though the `ProgressMonitor` can handle higher max values, the `SwingWorker` thread is ended by an  `IllegalArgumentException` when the value reaches 101.